# Custom caching setting for Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I initially have this for my Ext JS app;

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    disableCaching: false,
    enabled: true
});
```

Which is great because it will append Unix timestamp to my JS files making the browsers to not cache the files. I can then update my app without needing my users to clear the browser cache, or else there's a risk that the app will break.

The problem is, this will slow down the program loading (because the files need to be fetched every time). I'm just wondering if there's an easy way that I can manually set the **?_dc=1359704445222** (the timestamp value) so that the value will change only when I update my app.

**tl;dr: I want to be able to manually set the _dc parameter value for my Ext JS apps**

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic loading should only be used for development. Once you have release version, use [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/) to create production build of your application and deploy it to users.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the timestamp is a hardcoded thing in Sencha. You can easily change that by modifying your ext-all-dev.js (or if you are using a different file, look for similarities) and replace the following code:

Replace the following instances of Ext.Date.now() to your version number:

```
....
noCacheUrl = url + (this.getConfig('disableCaching') ? ('?' + this.getConfig('disableCachingParam') + '=' + Ext.Date.now()) : ''),
....
url = Ext.urlAppend(url, Ext.String.format("{0}={1}", me.cacheString, Ext.Date.now()));
```

Also replace the following instances of new Date().getTime() to your version number:

```
....
url = Ext.urlAppend(url, (options.disableCachingParam || me.disableCachingParam) + '=' + (new Date().getTime()));
....
params[cacheParam] = new Date().getTime();
```

Once you do that it should reflect in the UI as long as you have disableCaching turned on.